# AND operation between two sub queries

Tags: sql, database

These are my tables : https://ibb.co/mqX6wy

I was trying to find all customers who have both a loan and an account at the bank.

I am using MYSQL (PHP myadmin client)

The query should return **Hayes,Jones,Smith**

```
Select customer_name 
  from (
    SELECT borrower.customer_name 
      FROM borrower, loan 
      WHERE borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number) 
        AND (SELECT depositor.customer_name 
               FROM depositor,account 
               WHERE depositor.account_number = account.account_number)
```

Executing the above query throws up:

```
Error: *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near 'AND  (SELECT depositor.customer_name FROM depositor,account WHERE 
depositor.acco' at line 1*
```

Comment: What is this query **supposed** to do? Can you share the tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to receive?

Comment: Apologies, I am new to SO. I have updated the question with more info.

Comment: And what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 1):

According to your table structure i think you need below query

```
    Select t1.customer_name from 
    (
     SELECT b.customer_name FROM borrower b inner join
     on loan l b.loan_number = l.loan_number) as t1 
     inner join

    (
   SELECT depositor.customer_name FROM depositor d inner join account a on 
   d.account_number = a.account_number
    ) t2
    on t1.customer_name=t2.customer_name
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking your shared table structures looks following query works for you:

```
SELECT customer_name FROM  ( (SELECT borrower.customer_name 
FROM borrower INNER JOIN loan ON borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number) 
UNION (SELECT depositor.customer_name FROM depositor INNER JOIN account ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number) )
```

You can try inner join between those two queries as per your requirement:

```
SELECT customer_name 
FROM  ( 
         (SELECT borrower.customer_name FROM borrower INNER JOIN loan ON borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number) 
      AS bl INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT depositor.customer_name FROM depositor INNER JOIN account ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number) 
      ) 
AS da ON bl.customer_name=da.customer_name
```

Comment: This query returns union whereas I am looking for AND between the results of the two sub queries in the question.

Comment: then you can try this query ... with inner join between them instead on union >>> SELECT customer_name FROM 
( (SELECT borrower.customer_name FROM borrower INNER JOIN loan ON borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number) AS bl
INNER JOIN (SELECT depositor.customer_name FROM depositor INNER JOIN account ON depositor.account_number = account.account_number) ) AS da
ON bl.customer_name=da.customer_name

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see the point of joins when seemingly all your borrowers have a loan number and all your depositors have an account number. Assuming this is the case, you can use the following to get the intersection of the two tables.

```
(SELECT customer_name FROM borrower) INTERSECT (SELECT customer_name FROM depositor)
```

If that isn't the case, you could still use

```
(SELECT DISTINCT borrower.customer_name FROM borrower, loan WHERE borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number) INTERSECT (SELECT DISTINCT depositor.customer_name FROM depositor,account WHERE depositor.account_number = account.account_number)
```

Notice the use of `DISTINCT` to avoid repetitive values (ex: a Jones appears twice both on `borrower` and `depositor`)

Comment: I tried case 2 where I see the same error message as mentioned in the question :::::  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT DISTINCT depositor.customer_name FROM depositor,account WHERE depositor.' at line 1